# Read current system date and enter into text file

Tags: python

Could someone help me with my homework?

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
print(x)
text = x
plik = open("data.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
plik.write(text)
plik.close()
```

How to do it?

Comment: What help do you need? You have code, what's the problem? What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the following:

```py
import datetime # imports the datetime library
x = str(datetime.datetime.now()) # sets a variable x to be the current datatime, converted to string format

with open("data.txt", 'w+') as f: # creates (or opens and will overwrite if already exists) the file data.txt and changes the reference to be f
   f.write(x) # writes to data.txt the contents of the x variable
```

The problem with your above code is that `datetime.datetime.now()` does not return a `str` type, but rather a `datetime.datetime` type, which Python can't directly write.

Comment: Can you describe in sub-points what these codes mean?

Comment: @Nixan1662, it'll be saved with your current working directory. You can also save it to a specific location by changing `open("data.txt"...` to `open("/Users/jacobivanov/.../data.txt"...`

Comment: [This will help you greatly](https://www.w3schools.com/python/)

Comment: @Nixan1662, done. If this answers your question, consider marking this as the answer by clicking the checkmark. I would like to encourage you to reformat your questions to be less obvious "give me the answer" and actually explain what the problem is by showing errors, etc. Otherwise, some other users won't be as generous about not downvoting you like there's no tomorrow.